# SQL Website to convert SQL script into most concise version

Tags: sql, web, converters

Is there a website that will take your SQL code as is and reduce it to its most concise form.

For example you could copy in your script and statements such as:

```
Result Not Like 'A%' 
    And Result Not Like 'B%' 
         And Result Not Like 'C%' 
             And stuyear='11'
```

Will be automatically converted to:

```
Result Not Like '[ABC]%' 
    And stuyear='11'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of, even after searching around.

However, there are some products available for purchase that will optimize your SQL code such as [Dell's SQL Optimizer for Oracle](http://www.quest.com/sql-optimizer-for-oracle/), [DBSophic's Qure Optimizer](http://www.dbsophic.com/qure-optimizer.html), or Oracle's SQL Tuning Advisor. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.